# How to check MongoDB recovery time (auto failover) (sec)

Tags: mongodb, performance-testing, failover, recovery

How do you check for MongoDB's recovery time?

Recovery time (auto failover) (sec)
How do you check for the time it takes for MongoDB to elect a new primary

Comment: Use `rs.stepDown()` and observe how long it takes to elect a new primary.

Comment: based on this result, how can I tell how long it takes to elect a new primary?   'rs0:PRIMARY> rs.stepDown()
{
        "ok" : 1,
        "$clusterTime" : {
                "clusterTime" : Timestamp(1596786308, 1),
                "signature" : {
                        "hash" : BinData(0,"AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA="),
                        "keyId" : NumberLong(0)
                }
        },
        "operationTime" : Timestamp(1596786308, 1)'

Comment: after I used this command, how can I set it back as primary?

Comment: There is a stepUp command that should technically do that. In production you wouldn't use it and instead configure RS member priorities to favor your desired primary.